# C# ReSharper not finding usages of a method invoked with dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, dynamic, resharper

I have the following method

```
internal IPost InsertPost(dynamic json, FbPost fbPost, bool commit = false)
{
    EntityDataModelContext context = DataContext.GetDataContext();
    Post post = new Post();

    post.Link = json.link;
    post.LinkTitle = StringExtensions.UnicodeDecode(json.name);
    post.LinkDescription = StringExtensions.UnicodeDecode(json.description);
    post.LinkImage = json.picture;
    post.LinkSource = json.caption;

    post.Message = json.message;

    context.Posts.AddObject(post);

    if (commit)
        context.SaveChanges();

    return post;
}
```

And the following call:

```
var postRepo = PostFactory.CreateInternal();
post.Post = postRepo.InsertPost(json, post);
```

ReSharper doesn't find any usages even when clicking `Find Usages` in the context menu for the method call. Even though when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> it takes me to the method definition.

Is this expected behavior, or a known R# bug?

Comment: I think you're better off asking this on the youtrack site for resharper

Comment: What version of ReSharper do you have? Some of their `dynamic` support wasn't added until version 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

To find such dynamic usages, invoke "Find Usages Advanced" (AFAIR, In IDEA keyboard layout it is Ctrl-Alt-F7). In dialog there is option "Find late-bound references"